# Getting specific links from page and opening them automatically in another tab/window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with multiple table rows. Each row contains several links. I'm trying to get some links specifically and, using jquery, open them up in new windows. Here's what the page code looks like:

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="3" width="122" valign="top" height="100">

    <font class="verds1">
      <a href="esignup.php?eSessID=12871419" 
        title="Breakfast-650944"><font color="#4F4F4F"><b>Breakfast-650944</b></font></a>
      <br><br style="line-height: 7px"></font>

    <font class="verds1">
      <a href="esignup.php?eSessID=12873457"
        title="Lunch-654335"><font color="#FF0000"><b>Lunch-654335</b></font></a>
      <br><br style="line-height: 7px"></font>
      <font class="verds1" color="#000000"><b>f-</b></font>

    <font class="verds1">
      <a href="esignup.php?eSessID=1287141"
        title="Dinner-651092"><font color="#4F4F4F"><b>Dinner-651092</b></font></a>
      <br><br style="line-height: 7px"></font>

    <font class="verds1">
      <a href="esignup.php?eSessID=1282131"
        title="Dinner-651222"><font color="#4F4F4F"><b>Dinner-651222</b></font></a>
      <br><br style="line-height: 7px"></font>

  </td>
<tr>
```

In the above example, I'm looking to target only the links where the title contains the word 'Dinner', since the number following it will be different. Here there are two that match this criteria, but a page might have 5 or 6. I'm guessing I will have to put them in an array.

*My questions are:*

**How do I grab the urls from just the links with 'Dinner' in the title?**

**How do I open up a new tab/window for each of the urls?**

I have a pretty good idea on how to target the specific links, and I've been testing it out on firebug.

```
var link = $('td').find('a').filter(':contains("Dinner")');
console.log(link);
```

However at this point it's only return to me the actual text of 'Dinner-651222', not the url. And it only returns one result, instead of multiple ones like the document contains.

Any help on this would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
// get all a tag who have Dinner
var link = $('td').find('a').filter(':contains("Dinner")');
// get length of a
var linkLength = link.length;
// parse one by one and get URl from a tag
for (var i = 0; i < linkLength; i++) {
    // here is you all url
    var linkURL = $(link[i]).attr('href');
    // open each link in new window with custom settings
    var winOption = 'toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no, menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=400,height=300';
    window.open('http://localhost/mysite/' + linkURL, 'MyWindow', winOption);
    // end
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Neeraj.
The variable link, it's not an array, so how will it be able to hold all the links that are found?

Answer (score 0):

In regard to the second question. As far as I know, you can't open new tabs with Javascript. The best you can do is open a new window, that **depending on the browser configuration** it will open a new tab, or simply block it.

So, for opening a new window you can use:

```
<script>
    window.open("http://www.google.com", "google"); 
</script>
```